# Angular2 socket.io singleton websocket service for some components

Tags: angular, service, websocket, socket.io, singleton

Good day
Faced with a problem when writing chat on angular2. 
used the library socket.IO
to obtain the data used by the websocket service 
in which to import several components
the components of the received new messages
when the server sends them to the client

chatservice2.service.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

@Injectable()
export class ChatService {
    private url:string = 'http://websocketserver:1080/';
    private socket;

    sendMessage(message) {
        this.socket.emit('add-message', message);
    }

    getMessages() {
        let observable = new Observable(observer => {
            if (!this.socket) {
                console.log('create ws connection');
                let connectionOptions = {
                    'reconnection': true,
                    'reconnectionDelay': 10000, //milliseconds
                    'reconnectionDelayMax' : 15000, //milliseconds
                    'reconnectionAttempts': 30
                };
                this.socket = io(this.url, connectionOptions);
            }

            this.socket.on('message', (data) => {
                console.log('chatservice2.service next message observer', data, observer);
                observer.next(data);
            });
            return () => {
                this.socket.disconnect();
            };
        });
        return observable;
    }
}
```

dialog.component.ts

```
   //...
import { ChatService } from '../chatservice2.service';
//...

@Component({
    selector: 'app-dialog',
    templateUrl: './dialog.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dialog.component.css'],
    providers: [HttpService]
})
//...
export class DialogComponent implements OnInit {
    private wsChannel$;

    constructor(
        private chatService: ChatService
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('dialog component ngOnInit');
        this.wsChannel$ = this.chatService
            .getMessages()
            .subscribe(message => {
                console.log('message dialog.component', message);
                this.someFunc(message);
                //...
            });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.wsChannel$.unsubscribe();
    }
    //...

}
```

If you open a component (dialog.component.ts) for the first time. 
Messages come. Everything is OK.
If you navigate to another component. 
Then return to the dialog.component.ts messages will stop coming , that is 24 line console.log('message dialog.component', message) will not fire.
If you remove this.wsChannel$.unsubscribe(); (line 32) in the method ngOnDestroy after 2 transitions in the component dialog.component.ts console will be triggered 2 times , one for incoming websocket message from the server. If you do 10 pull-on feature, the console will fire 10 times on a single websocket message.
The question is how can I fix it ? How to get unsubscribe method worked while leaving the components and the messages from chatservice2.service.ts are not duplicated. What is my mistake?
Thanks in advance for the help